Issue with Enums and inputting
I have an issue with invalid enum input when trying to update my database model. The error is below. I am not sure what I am doing wrong
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input value for enum recipientstatus

Here is the enum I used and the model
class RecipientStatus(enum.Enum):
    WAITING_TO_SEND = "WAITING_TO_SEND"
    PENDING_TO_SEND = "PENDING_TO_SEND"

class Recipient(db.Model):
    status = db.Column(db.Enum(RecipientStatus))

The code below is a sample of what I want the enum to do. For some reason, it is not recognizing the enum of the code
for recipients in recipients:
            recipient.status = RecipientStatus.FAILED_TO_SEND.value
            recipient.status_changed_at = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
        db.session.commit()

This is the alembic command if it helps
def upgrade():
    recipient_status_enum = ENUM(
        "WAITING_TO_SEND",
        "PENDING_TO_SEND",
        name="recipientstatus",
    )
    recipient_status_enum.create(op.get_bind(), checkfirst=True)
    op.add_column(
        "recipient", sa.Column("status", recipient_status_enum, nullable=True)
    )

I tried changing the enum. I tried without the .value of the ENUM but it still gives me an error

It seems like FAILED_TO_SEND is not part of the enum you've written:
class RecipientStatus(enum.Enum):
    WAITING_TO_SEND = "WAITING_TO_SEND"
    PENDING_TO_SEND = "PENDING_TO_SEND"

Try to add it and run it again.
